# Add additional information to a order after payment in Big Commerce

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I would like to add additional information to a customers order after they have made the payment and landed on the confirmation page.

I sell products that have to be installed into the customers car. I would like to capture the customers car make model and year of registration (perferably after the order have been taken to not distract from the sale process). 
I was hoping this could be done with the Bigcommerce API; where I could present the customer with a form they can fill in, after they have purchased, on the Order confirmation page and the data can get added to the customers order somehow.

Is this possible or would it be easier to caputre the car details in the cart or checkout?

BTW: not all products will come with vehicle installation.

Has anyone done anything similar using the Big Commerce API?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the customer add it in as a note during check-out, this might be the most economical route.

Answer (score 0):

Not as of today. The PUT request for orders does not allow the same fields as POST (order creation) - http://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/orders#put-ordersidjson

But, this is slated to be pushed in the coming weeks. Then you will be able to simply execute a PUT request on a captured order to update the "staff_notes" or "customer_message" field.

However, if you want to capture this during order creation via API, you can already do something like the following -

```
    $createFields = array('customer_id'=>0, 'date_created' => 'Tue, 20 Nov 2012 00:00:00 +0000','status_id'=>1,'billing_address' => array( "first_name"=> "Trisha", "last_name"=> "McLaughlin", "company"=> "", "street_1"=> "12345 W Anderson Ln", "street_2"=> "", "city"=> "Austin", "state"=> "Texas", "zip"=> "78757", "country"=> "United States", "country_iso2"=> "US", "phone"=> "", "email"=> "elsie@example.com" ), "shipping_addresses" => array(), "external_source" => "POS", "products" => array(), "staff_notes" => "some notes here" );
print_r(Bigcommerce::createOrder($createFields));
```